# How to tell Kubernetes not to send traffic to a pod right after creation

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes nginx deployment that, when I redeploy it again with `kubectl apply -f file.yaml` it's having a small downtime, around 3 or 5 seconds.

I'm using a readinessProbe to tell Kubernetes that traffic shouldn't be sent to that pod until the readiness works but as soon as the deployment begins (even while the `initialDelaySeconds` haven't finished I'm getting 502/503 errors that finish as soon as the readiness works.

So, I thought that, until the readinessProbe is successful, that pod shouldn't be taken into account by Kubernetes, but that's not what I'm seeing.

If I set up an `initialDelaySeconds` of 10, I get around 10 seconds of outage. If I reduce it to 0, I still have a small downtime, until the readiness works.

The relevant parts of the service/deployment that I'm using are

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: 'name'
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    project: 'project'
    role: bastion
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: 'bastion'
spec:
  replicas: 6
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 6
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: 'bastion'
          image: 'my-image'
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command: ['sh', '-c', '/usr/sbin/nginx -s quit;']
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /myendpoint
              port: 80
            periodSeconds: 60
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            failureThreshold: 15
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /myendpoint
              port: 80
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 5m
              memory: 5Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 50Mi
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: 'imagesecrets'
```

Is there something that I'm missing here? What kind of changes I could try to debug/fix this problem?

Comment: Could you provide the pod spec?

Comment: Are u using recreate as the deployment strategy ?

Comment: I've added the specs @anemyte

Comment: I'm using a rollingUpdate strategy @AvinashKumar

Comment: I have glanced through and in my opinion `maxUnavailable: 0` is the problem, make it 3 or some...

Answer (score 0):

You've used

```
periodSeconds: 60
initialDelaySeconds: 15
failureThreshold: 15
```

for the `livenessProbe` but you don't have any defined for the readiness probe. I think that's why you're seeing the errors. Try to define the `initialDelaySeconds` for `readinessProbe` as well

Also, to debug this, you can describe a newly created pod. You'll see at the end all the events that are happening, including the readiness probe event